# How to make jpeg compression with lowest CPU usage?

Tags: performance, jpeg, intel-ipp

I need to convert raw image data to jpeg.
But I don't need anything special in terms of best quality, or minumum size etc.
Only thing I need is minumum CPU usage.
I am new to jpeg compression.

Can you please advice about which parameters will have the lowest CPU usage while converting jpeg?

I would like to use IPP(intel performance library).
An example from IPP jpeg library would be great.
But any sample from any other jpeg library also will be apprecited.

And if you know any jpeg library which is more performant than IPP's jpeg library, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: http://libjpeg-turbo.virtualgl.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean 'fastest'? As in 'uses the cpu for the least amount of time'?

If you just mean CPU load, then the best way to lower CPU usage (if you want to do something else at the same time), is to ask the operating system to downprioritize the program.